# SQL Statement - Is NULL & IS Not Null;

Tags: sql, excel

I want to extract the data from "Registration" and "Confirmation" columns where "Confirmation" is not blank and "Drive_Update" column is blank. any help would be greatly appreciated.

I believe the logic i am writing is slightly incorrect. No data is currently being extracted.

The statement I have written below:

```
 SELECT [Registration],[Confirmation]
 FROM [$vOrderWorkSheets$$] 
 WHERE [Confirmation] IS NOT NULL AND [Drive_Update] IS NULL;
```

**Database is excel workbook

From the below table including headers I would like lines 1 & 3 extracted

```
      Registration | Confirmation | Drive_Update
      ABC123       | Success      |
      DCE453       | Error        | Not Required
      UTY123       | Success      |
```

[image]

Comment: If "blank" means `NULL` then the query seems OK. If "blank" means the empty string or just white space, you need to check for that instead.

Comment: @stickybit blank is an empty cell in an excel workbook, therefore could be considered as white space. Do you know how to check for white space?

Comment: If there's `trim()` (or `ltrim()` or `rtrim()`) you could try `trim([Confirmation]) <> '' AND trim([Drive_Update]) = ''`.

Comment: @MitchWheat added an example of the table (Unfortunately unable to post image)

Answer (score -1):

I would expect that the problem is that the "blanks" are empty strings.  If so, you can account for this:

```
 SELECT [Registration],[Confirmation]
 FROM [$vOrderWorkSheets$$] 
 WHERE Confirmation <> '' AND
       (Drive_Update IS NULL OR Drive_Update = '');
```

Note that `<> ''` also filters out `NULL` values, so no explicit comparison is needed.

It is also possible that "blank" consists of a series of spaces (which would allow you to use `TRIM()` or `REPLACE()`).  However, "blank" could also have hidden characters in them.  If that is the case, more investigation is needed.